# How to check EOF in server-side python standard input

Tags: python, stdin, eof

So I'm trying to have the HackerRank server check a code for me. I build a dictionary of names and their respective phone numbers. The HackerRank server uses stdin to query names for their numbers by entering names on successive lines until it runs out of names.

I'm aware that in the shell one uses Ctrl+D (Unix) or Ctrl+Z (Windows) to signal EOF, but I'm not sure how to set up my code so that the program stops trying to read from stdin --when the server stops entering queries-- and prints the phone numbers. This is my best guess as to a solution:

```
N=input()               #number of phonebook entries
D={}
for i in range(N):      #build phonebook as dictionary using stdin
    name=raw_input()
    number=raw_input()
    D[name]=number


for i in range(10000):  #queries are then entered with a max number of 10^4
    try:
        line=raw_input()
        if line in D.keys():
            print line + "=" + D[line]     #print name=phonenumber
        else:
            print "Not found"

    except EOFError:     #break out of loop if EOF is reached
        break
```

This doesn't seem to do it and I'm wondering if it's because I'm not doing the EOF reading right or if it's some peculiarity in the original problem that I may not be interpreting properly.

Answer (score 0):

The `line` will be the empty string `''` when you reach end-of-file.